# How to use event delegation to target desired class?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Okay so I was wondering how I could target the class that is being generated from innerHTML. I tried creating an if statement inside and outside of the scope but it kept saying that I could not target the class of likeButton because it hasn't been generated yet I assume. I'm trying to target the like button that would be created on click so that I can write an event delegation because I'm trying to store data when the user clicks the like button into localStorage.

```js
const myApp = {};

myApp.key = "6bc738f69e2da4c6404c04bfe106d46c";
myApp.url =
  " https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=6bc738f69e2da4c6404c04bfe106d46c&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_average.asc&include_adult=false&page=2&include_video=false&release_date.gte=2000&vote_count.gte=1500&with_watch_monetization_types=flatrate&providers";
myApp.init = () => {};
const submitButton = document.querySelector(".submitButton");

//  3 fetches to obtain 60 movie objects for array
myApp.getNewArray = (year, movieRating) => {
  // 1st fetch
  fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=6bc738f69e2da4c6404c04bfe106d46c&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_average.${movieRating}&include_adult=false&page=1&include_video=false&${year}&vote_count.gte=1500&with_watch_monetization_types=flatrate&providers`
    )
    .then((results) => {
      return results.json();
    })
    .then((jsonData) => {
      jsonData.results.forEach((arrayItem) => {
        myApp.movieArray.push(arrayItem);
      });
    });

  // 2nd fetch
  fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=6bc738f69e2da4c6404c04bfe106d46c&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_average.${movieRating}&include_adult=false&page=2&include_video=false&${year}&vote_count.gte=1500&with_watch_monetization_types=flatrate&providers`
    )
    .then((results) => {
      return results.json();
    })
    .then((jsonData) => {
      jsonData.results.forEach((arrayItem) => {
        myApp.movieArray.push(arrayItem);
      });
    });

  // 3rd fetch
  fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=6bc738f69e2da4c6404c04bfe106d46c&language=en-US&sort_by=vote_average.${movieRating}&include_adult=false&page=3&include_video=false&${year}&vote_count.gte=1500&with_watch_monetization_types=flatrate&providers`
    )
    .then((results) => {
      return results.json();
    })
    .then((jsonData) => {
      jsonData.results.forEach((arrayItem) => {
        myApp.movieArray.push(arrayItem);
      });

      myApp.movieArrayIndecisive = myApp
        .movieRandomizer(myApp.movieArray)
        .splice(0, 5);

      myApp.movieArrayHopeless = myApp
        .movieRandomizer(myApp.movieArray)
        .splice(0, 1);

      myApp.movieArrayDecisive = myApp.movieArray.splice(0, 10);

      document.querySelector(".inventory").innerHTML = ""; //clear grid

      //display 10, 5, or 1 movie depending on user selection
      if (myApp.results.includes("Decisive")) {
        myApp.displayImages(myApp.movieArrayDecisive);
      } else if (myApp.results.includes("Indecisive")) {
        myApp.displayImages(myApp.movieArrayIndecisive);
      } else {
        myApp.displayImages(myApp.movieArrayHopeless);
      }
      location.href = "#grid";
    });
};

// Store the user input from dropdown menu into a new array
function getSelectedItems() {
  const items = document.getElementsByClassName("selectVal");

  myApp.results = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const item = items[i];
    const userInput = item.options[item.selectedIndex].value;
    myApp.results.push(userInput);
  }
}

// array randomizer
myApp.movieRandomizer = (array) => {
  return array.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
};

//function to obtain streaming providers for movie
myApp.getProviders = function(providers, listEl) {
  const providerContainer = document.createElement("div");
  const providerLink = document.createElement("a");
  const errorMessage = document.createElement("p");

  errorMessage.className = "errorMessage";

  if (providers) {
    providerLink.innerText = `Where to Watch`;
    providerLink.setAttribute("href", providers.link);
    providerLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    providerContainer.className = "providerContainer";
    providerLink.className = "providerLink";
    providerContainer.append(providerLink);
    listEl.appendChild(providerContainer);
  } else {
    listEl.append(errorMessage);
    errorMessage.innerText = `Not Available in Canada`;
  }
};

// Create a function to display the images from the array
myApp.displayImages = function(array) {
  //getting streaming providers for each movie
  array.forEach((arrayItem) => {
    const listEl = document.createElement("li");
    const imgGrid = document.querySelector(".inventory");
    fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${arrayItem.id}/watch/providers?api_key=6bc738f69e2da4c6404c04bfe106d46c`
      )
      .then((results) => {
        return results.json();
      })
      .then((jsonData) => {
        myApp.getProviders(jsonData.results.CA, listEl);
      });

    listEl.innerHTML = `
          <div class="card">
            <div class="moviePoster">
              <img src= "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${arrayItem.poster_path}"/>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class='likeButton'>
              <i class="fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          `;
    imgGrid.appendChild(listEl);
  });
};


likeButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("this is working");
});

// Execute this code based on user click
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  myApp.movieArray = [];

  const yearChoice = document.querySelector("#movieYear");
  const scoreChoice = document.querySelector("#movieScore");

  myApp.getNewArray(yearChoice.value, scoreChoice.value);

  //Stretch goals
  // Like button and favourite's list using localStorage
  // Fix CSS
  // Cleanup code
  // Store if and array statements into a function
  // Use a drawer to save our favourite's list
  // Card flip animation
  //
});

myApp.init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Movie Randomizer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/13dd608ac9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=M+PLUS+Rounded+1c:wght@100;300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="theater-sign">
      <div class="sign-top">
        <div class="sign-lines">
          <div class="sign-line"></div>
          <div class="sign-line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sign-title">Decision Fatigue?</div>
        <div class="sign-lines">
          <div class="sign-line"></div>
          <div class="sign-line"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="theatre-grid">
          <div class="show-details" style="color: #f8f0e3">
            <p class="neon">Scroll no more!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <form action="">
      <div class="formSelects">
        <label for="movieYear">Movie Release Date</label>
        <select id="movieYear" class="selectVal">
          <option value="primary_release_date.gte=2009-12-31&primary_release_date.lte=2022-07-14">
            2010 - 2022
          </option>
          <option value="primary_release_date.gte=1999-12-31&primary_release_date.lte=2010-01-01">
            2000 - 2009
          </option>
          <option value="primary_release_date.gte=1989-12-31&primary_release_date.lte=2000-12-31">
            1990 - 1999
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="formSelects">
        <label for="movieScore">Classics or Trash?</label>
        <select id="movieScore" class="selectVal">
          <option value="desc" selected="selected">
            Give me a classic
          </option>
          <option value="asc">In the Mood for Trash</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="formSelects">
        <label for="movieDecisiveness">How long have you been scrolling?</label
                    >
                    <select id="movieDecisiveness" class="selectVal">
                        <option value="Decisive" selected="selected">
                            Just started
                        </option>
                        <option value="Indecisive">My mind is numb</option>
                        <option value="Hopeless">Help me!</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <button onClick="getSelectedItems()" class="submitButton">
                    Recommendations
                </button>
            </form>

            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="grid" id="grid">
                    <ul class="inventory"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your event delegation that calls `resultsDelegation()`?

Comment: `event.target.classList.contains("")` can never be true. You can't have an empty class name.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Most of the code you posted has little to do with the question.

Comment: @Barmar I posted the entire working code I was using and I included the event delegation section in the javascript? The class was empty because previously I had a console.log there to check if I could access it, but it kept returning undefined so I wasn't sure if I should keep it or not.

Comment: Where is the event delegation section? I see the definition of `resultsDelegation()`, but nothing that calls it.

Comment: oh, I see. I updated the code to reproduce the error, but after reading some similar questions it said to use an event delegation and I was still getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an event listener to `likeButton`, because it doesn't exist yet. You need to use delegation from the container element that it will be added to.

```
// Delegation

function resultsDelegation(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (event.target.classList.contains("likeButton")) {
    console.log("this is working");
  }
}

document.querySelector(".inventory").addEventListener("click", resultsDelegation);
```